# iOS InApp rating exceed limit

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Hello Thanks in Advance,

Am currently working on App Store InApp rating. I knew about the policy that apple allows only 3 rating once in 365 days.
So I would like to know that what happens if I request for rating more than 3 times in 365 days. Does it still show the rating popup and refuse to submit or it works something like in the developer environment(Rating and submitting but do not reflect in the app store).

Answer (score 2):

No matter how many times you request the review prompt, the system will show the prompt a maximum of three times in a 365-day period.

Development: Shown every time the you request the prompt.